# Slack: change browser to open links from desktop app

Tags: slack

I use two browsers on my laptop - Brave for my personal stuff (Facebook, personal email, interesting things I want to read) and Firefox for my work browsing (work email, internal webpages, work communication). Normally I like having my default browser for the computer set to Brave (personal), since most of the time I use the laptop outside of work.

I now have the Slack desktop app to keep in better communication with folks at work. But when I click on links from there, it goes to Brave where I am not logged-in to anything work related.

Is there a way to change the browser that Slack opens without changin my system wide default browser?

I'm on a Mac, Mojave, if that helps.

Comment: I asked slack's support team and the answer is no. They'll pass the feedback to the product team. Hopefully we'll see this feature one day. [here's the ticket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZMJD.png)

Answer (score 24):

You could use *Browserosaurus* or *Finicky* or even a combination of them.

When *Browserosaurus* is set up as default browser, and a link is clicked, it shows a list of installed/configured browsers in which to open that link that can be selected with a one-character shortcut.

*Finicky* can also be setup as a default browser and it allows me to setup rules that can launch a suitable browser based upon those rules.  For example: open slack.com links in Firefox, Box.com in Safari and so on.

References:

- Browserosaurus - https://github.com/will-stone/browserosaurus
- Finicky - https://github.com/johnste/finicky

Comment: Finicky worked just great for me. Now I can choose in which browser the links will be open depending on the app where the link appeared. Here is my config:

```
module.exports = {
  defaultBrowser: "Safari",
    handlers: [
     {
       match: ({ opener }) =>
         opener.bundleId === "com.tinyspeck.slackmacgap",
       browser: "Firefox"
     } 
    ]
}
```

Comment: Would love a Windows equivalent of Finicky! +1 anyway.

Comment: Finicky worked really nice! Thanks for sharing!!!

Comment: 2023 update - Finicky RULES!
Be sure to check out the Finicky Kickstart for super-easy configuration:
https://finicky-kickstart.vercel.app/

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 24):

I tried many options; nothing worked for me.
Firefox is my default browser but slack opened links Opera. So i uninstalled Opera. Then slack opened links in Chrome.

Here is what i did that worked for me.

- I use Kubuntu and firefox is already the default browser (verified from firefox's settings)
- I want slack to open links in firefox
- Open ***System Settings -> Applications -> Default Applications***
- Select ***Firefox*** as the default for ***Web Browser***.

Now slack opens links in firefox.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked for Kubuntu 21.04.

Comment: Worked a treat on Ubuntu 21.10 too.  Somehow Chrome was the default, even though on starting chrome complained it was not the default and firefox didn't.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this Firefox Workaround helps you:

1. Open web link in slack
2. In the Firefox browser instance opened by Slack write "about:profiles" in adress field
3. Change the profile used as default to your regular profile

found on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103461/slack-shows-opened-links-to-browser-as-another-slack-instance-in-task-bar

Answer (score 6):

I'm looking to do the same thing, for the same reason.

Even though you can set the default browser system wide, there doesn't appear to be a way to set the default browser per app (e.g. for Slack). There also isn't a way to set a preference in Slack for which browser to launch.

The only option I've found so far is Choosy (https://www.choosyosx.com) but it costs money, though you can trial it for 40 days or so.

I'm trying it out now and works nicely so far.

Comment: Tried choosyosx, it works great. Thanks for the mention.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this straight forward on mac OS, but on Linux you can: [Default Browser for certain application | https://askubuntu.com/a/1188672](https://askubuntu.com/a/1188672)
Considering moving to the Linux world may be one option.

---

EDIT: Desktop entries are not part of macOS, but maybe one can mimic it by using AppleScript and booting applications from there, or writing a shellscript and booting application from the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative solution is to open Slack on your favorite browser and open links directly there.

Comment: i do prefer the app but this actually addresses the need without adding complexity.  context is the driver, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Default Browser for certain application](https://askubuntu.com/a/1188672/1192462)

The above answer by [@maxim](https://askubuntu.com/users/699579/maxim) deals with how to set default browser per app, and fortunately, it uses slack as the example.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up. There's no way in Slack to specify a browser. But with the Firefox Containers extension (I have both the Facebook and Multi-account Container extensions), I can better compartamentalize how I use my tabs. So, now everything defaults to Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 10 and frustrated by this problem daily.  Annoying as it is, instead of clicking on the item to open it, if you right-click you can copy the link and paste it into your work-related browser.  I don't know how / if this would work on a mac though.

Answer (score -2):

In windows 10, i solved this by doing the following:

```
Start > Settings > Apps > Default Apps > Web Browser -> Your browser.
```

Comment: This is setting the default browser, the OP is explicitly asking for something different

Comment: Although it indeed is not what the OP was asking for, well, that is exactly what I was looking for (Win 11), so… thx!

Answer (score -3):

If you using Ubuntu (Linux) you can just go to `about:preferences` and  click on "make default" button.

[image: Example]

Answer (score -7):

on mac: `System Preferences -> General -> Default web browser`

Comment: I'm not asking to change my default browser. I'm asking to have Slack open links in something *other* than my default browser. At that time, I had Brave as default (and personal stuff) but Slack was for work. I wanted Slack to open links in Firefox, not the default. I didn't want to change the default browser to the Mac as a whole.

Comment: yes, that's not perfect but that's a workaround that might still be useful for other people.

Comment: Sadly, this workaround doesn't work - Slack doesn't use the system default, at least not on MacOS.